# Dynamically change an image on a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m having some difficulties trying to dynamically change an image.

```
<a href="#no-reload" id="dropMenuButton49" class="dropMenuButton">
<input id="searchEngineImage" type="image" src="http://example.com/image.php?i=yahoo-icon.png">
<input type="image" src="images/down.png" name="dropDown">
</a>
```

I need to change the first one: http://example.com/image.php?i=yahoo-icon.png.

Is this possible with jQuery or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#searchEngineImage').attr({'src':'some-image.jpg'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can change it dynamically by jquery... Check this:

http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#searchEngineImage').attr('src', "http://some.other/image.png");
```

Comment: sorry didn't see @Andy's answer. keeping it because of the different approach to the function `attr`